# React : Set state of array in object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

**Problem**

---

Lets assume I have the following React component. It contains an object as an state. This object in turn has an array in it.

**My goal** is to update this state.

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {

      contactFields: {
        opsAreaCode: "",
        instructions: "",
        contact: [
          {
            email: "",
            phone: "",
            type: "",
          }
        ]
      }
}
```

**My current solution**
Does not work.

```
this.setState(
  (prevState) => ({
    contactFields: {
      ...prevState.contactFields,
      contact[0]: { email: value },
    },
  })
```

);

contact[0] => Does not work? How can I access the index of an array? And how do i add a whole new input to that array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like that :

```
const tmpConcat = this.state.concatFields.concat;
tmpConcat[0] = {email: value}
this.setState(
  (prevState) => ({
    contactFields: {
      ...prevState.contactFields,
      concat: tmpConcat,
    },
  }),
  () => Log.info("CALLBACK", this.state.limitsetup)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. Becareful, contact should be small because it will reallocate.

```js
this.setState(
  (prevState) => ({
    contactFields: {
      ...prevState.contactFields,
      contact: [{email: "fakemail@ggle.com"},...prevstate.contact],
    },
  }),
);
```